# HTML Embeded Prezi: autoplay on page load

Tags: html, iframe, prezi

I'm looking to embed a prezi on a website and have it autoplay at 4 seconds when the page is loaded without the user having to click the play button, then the cog wheel and then #seconds.

The prezi iframe looks like this. ( this is not my prezi, just a random one online)

```
<iframe id="iframe_container" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen="" mozallowfullscreen="" allowfullscreen="" width="550" height="400" src="https://prezi.com/embed/_ueivw8ad8xx/?bgcolor=ffffff&amp;lock_to_path=0&amp;autoplay=0&amp;autohide_ctrls=0&amp;landing_data=bHVZZmNaNDBIWnNjdEVENDRhZDFNZGNIUE43MHdLNWpsdFJLb2ZHanI5N1pSeHI4aEw3YmNTZCtwR3dmczBheS9BPT0&amp;landing_sign=mcmZqoFuXziC3VzyNhpywHa6wEOcfwZRQZhRqzgwWVE"></iframe>
```

I'm guessing it has something to do with this autoplay=0&amp , but no matter what I change it to. Doesn't affect the result.

```
autoplay=4s
autoplay=4&amp
autoplay=4s&amp
```

This may not be possible, just wondering if someone knows.